# Prevent photoanalysisd from spinning up fans

Tags: macos, catalina

At times I hear my MacBook (Mid-2015, 15" retina) get loud, fans whirring. It becomes pretty hot to touch.

I check Activity Monitor: photoanalysisd is using near 100% CPU.

[What is "photoanalysisd" and why is it using 77% of my CPU?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/310594/150109) says that it's due to changes in Photos.app... I have never used Photos.app. None of the answers on that question help me.

I just Force Quit photoanalysisd now whenever this happens, and haven't noticed any problems.

But it's frustrating when this happens.

How do I stop photoanalysisd from hogging CPU?

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: Did you try all the answers in the linked question just now?

Comment: @nohillside none of them are newer than my question, and I remember reading that question before I asked this one. I don't have this photoanalysisd problem anymore so I can't actually test answers now.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to AppleID > iCloud and disable Photos.
- Go run Photos app and verify there are no libraries, delete all images or delete the library so when you relaunch Photos is asks to create a library.
- Repeat these steps for every user on your Mac in Accounts
- Restart the Mac.

At that point you might need look into logs to see what’s triggering the daemon to do work or run a `sysdiagnose` on the process. Also, Photos can have many libraries, so you might need to switch libraries to locate the system library or other ones. Photo analysis can run on any library - not just the one you expect when you launch the app.

Comment: Im not using iCloud, but still got this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check console for photoanalysisd. I suspect it’s restarting over and over. Mine is.